# How can I install using gem when I keep getting this zlib error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, zlib, rails-upgrade

I recently installed rails 4.1.8 from the repos in ubuntu. I installed ruby 2.0.0. I want to update to rails 4.2.0. I rvm'd to ruby 2.0.0. I try to update rails using

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.0
```

but receive this error

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

zlib1g-dev is already installed. I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks

Comment: I tried with ruby v 2.4.0. Didn't help. I tried re-installing ruby, re-installed gem....

Answer (score 0):

I decided to simply uninstall everyting, a la

```
aptitude purge rails
```

Then start from scratch using [this](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/15.04) guide